# Cannot properly display the numbers after reading them from a txt file (C++)

Tags: c++, file-io

I need to write a code that reads a txt file (containing 2 columns, the 1st column is int type, the second one is double type)

13 2.7

42 3.1

78 1.6

37 7.8

17 2.7

then prints out a table look like this:

1 |    13  |    2.7

2 |    42   |   3.1

3 |    78   |   1.6

4 | 37     | 7.8

5 | 17    |  2.7

But after running the code, the out put is like:

[image: click]

I dont understand why this happen. Could someone please show me where i did wrong? Thank you. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream in_file;
string filename;
const int NUM_LINES = 10;
const int NUM_COLUMNS = 2;
const int COLUMN_WIDTH = 10;
cout << "In order to process, please enter the file name: ";
cin >> filename;
in_file.open(filename.c_str());
if (!in_file.is_open())
{
    cout << "Cannot open file" << endl;
}
else
{   
    for (int k = 0; k < NUM_LINES; ++k)
    {
        int intValue;
        double doubleValue;
        in_file >> intValue >> doubleValue;
        cout << setw(COLUMN_WIDTH) << (k + 1) << " | ";
        cout << setw(COLUMN_WIDTH) << intValue << " | ";
        cout << setw(COLUMN_WIDTH) << doubleValue << endl;
    }
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the unreadable screenshot?

Comment: Why are you not reading two integers and the separators? (also missing reading the end of line)

Comment: http://imgur.com/qvirDWF Here is the link :D

Comment: @EdHeal the separator is the output, the file only contains 2 columns of number

Comment: Why not copy 'n' paste the text? Some of us have better things to do than download images or also viewing on mobile devices

Comment: So what is an example of the input file?

Comment: Wait if you have two input files then what is the third column?

Comment: The first column is just the order number that i added @Curious

Comment: What is an example of the input file?

Comment: I edited the post, you can see the example now :D~ @Curious

Comment: Dude, it's working fine in my pc. The problem is in your input file.

Comment: Could you copy and paste the exact contents of the input file to the question? There's obviously some weird conflicts going on.

Comment: @Spencer4134 I did ;;A ;;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code runs as intended on my machine. I believe that you have characters in your file, perhaps some formatting or header for the data that you did not account for.

Comment: Possibly the input file is in UTF-16 format and has a Byte-Order-Mark at the top.

Comment: ;;___;; so what am i supposed to do. The file's in Unicode format @Erich

Answer (score 0):

This code should work with simple input redirection

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
#include <string>
using std::string;
#include <cstdlib>
#include <utility>
using std::pair;

int main() {

    int integer;
    double decimal_value;

    vector<pair<int, double>> pair_values;
    while (cin >> integer >> decimal_value) {
        pair_values.push_back({integer, decimal_value});
    }

    // print out the values in a table format
    for (auto val : pair_values) {
        cout << val.first << '\t' << '|' << '\t'
            << val.second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And this should work with file streams

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
#include <fstream>
using std::ifstream;
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
#include <string>
using std::string;
#include <cstdlib>
#include <utility>
using std::pair;

int main() {

    // get the input file stream
    string filename;
    ifstream fin;
    cout << "Please enter the input filename : ";
    cin >> filename;
    fin.open(filename.c_str());
    if (!fin) {
        cerr << "Could not open file with filename " << filename << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int integer;
    double decimal_value;

    vector<pair<int, double>> pair_values;
    while (fin >> integer >> decimal_value) {
        pair_values.push_back({integer, decimal_value});
    }

    // print out the values in a table format
    for (auto val : pair_values) {
        cout << val.first << '\t' << '|' << '\t'
            << val.second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not `vector<pair<int, double>>`?

Comment: You are right! I should have definitely used that. It is much more efficient :) Don't know why I didn't

Comment: Curious, this is the second time you helped me, thank you T__T I'm trying the code now, let see...

Comment: Oh really? Hahaha you are welcome! I wish there was a way I could follow you on stack overflow :)

Comment: The program terminates without any output =))) I looked at your profile to see if there's a FB acc but see nothing lol

Comment: Wait how? That is weird, could you try the input file you specified with spaces? It works for me..

Comment: Could you let me know how you compiled and ran the project?